# How and when is keyboard data encoded from keyboard to application?

Tags: linux, osx, windows, keyboard, hardware

How and when is keyboard data encoded? I just want to know in basic terms the process from the keyboard to the application; when is the data from the keyboard encoded? Is it encoded by the keyboard processor, by the operating system, by the application?

Just another question on the side: if the keyboard data is encoded by the operating system, what is the default encoding of Windows, MacOS and Linux? Do any of them use UTF-8?

Comment: Your main question should be more than adequately answered by the dupe (let me know if it isn't). Your secondary question should be asked separately but we can only answer for Linux and OSX here. I suggest you ask it on [su] instead.